# code blocks 8.02 console program not outputting cout statements with SDL

Tags: c++, console, mingw, sdl

im currently using the SDL-devel-1.2.13-mingw32 library in code blocks 8.02. with the mingw 5.1.6 installed separately on C:\ this program compiles and runs with no errors but i can't see the last system("pause"); on the screen. When i press any key, it of course skips over the system("pause"); then code blocks tells me that it successful ran. It also doesn'w show the cout << " SDL \n"; WTF?

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << " SDL \n";
    cout << endl;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) == -1) {
        cerr << "Failed to initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);
    system("pause");`
    return 0;
}

Comment: small details: im using windows XP, and I would like to use the console to debug larger SDL programs. but i wrote this to simply demonstrate my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the options used to compile SDL, console output may be redirected to files called stdout.txt and stderr.txt -- this is the default for most Windows builds.

See this wiki article for a solution: http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_Console

Comment: i tried the all that code and the console is giving me alien output

Comment: where would the *.txt files be?

Comment: In the program's working directory. They may be deleted when the program terminates.

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, however there are two lines you can add to the beginning of your main() to get cout working:

```
freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
freopen("CON", "w", stderr);
```

Comment: Depends on what version of SDL you are using :) it worked for me, sorry this is horrifically late but what did you try?